# What to do with unused pins on a 1000BaseT RJMAG jack

Tags: pcb-design, communication, ethernet, rj45, network-interface

Trying to figure out what to do with the unused wires heading into the magnetics on an RJMG2330A1610ER Ethernet/USB jack.  Due to the craziness in manufacturing in the world I am forced to find a replacement connector for a board I am working on.

The board only uses a 10/100 Base-T transceiver(DP83848-EP), but the only jack I can find that meets my needs is an RJ 1000 Base-T one.

I figured I could wire up R10-R12, and R4-R6 to meet my needs for the 100 Base-T, but I was worried about how to properly wire up the rest of the pins, or just leave them NC.[image]

Anyone have a little more experience here or can point me to some nice resources?  Striking out so far on my own.  Thanks for any help!

EDIT1:

[image]

Comment: You can leave them unconnected or terminate them with a resistor. The 100BaseT cable doesn't have those pairs anyway.

Comment: @Gus how does your original magjack terminate the unused pins? What's the type of the original magjack?

Comment: It was a mtj-usb-88jx1-fs-pg-lh-m41c, and like @LiorBilia mentioned, it didn't have those.  I will update my original post to show the old config.